# What would be best as the first free CiviCRM ad on StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

StackExchange allows us to define our own ads:

> The goal is to help visitors find out about the cool stuff your community is doing and help promote activities they find important. And it’s all visible right there on the sidebar next to every question, and the homepage.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/

The form the ads take is:

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

[1]: http://image-url
[2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

where the ad is a 220 x 250 gif (not animated) or png.

What should we advertise? It could upcoming events, eg the monthly intro webinars, CiviCons, etc. A signup for our newsletter would be a good step for involving people. Noting our hashtag or twitter handle? While we get developers here, I'm not sure if we should be advertising our irc channel since this is a better place for Q&A, and irc will turn off most non-developers. Maybe a gentle ask for money (not my preference).

Comment: Community Ads are a feature of sites when the graduate, so this feature not enabled at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Robert Cartino. We'll be back at you on this one once we graduate from public beta.

Comment: Excellent suggestion! I'll followup next week.